# Creating a daily account log from a Pandas expense file in data frame format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an expense file that I am trying to read in and from this file create a daily log.  A small subset of the file that extends over years is shown below, for a few days in January 2015.

```
Date,Checking_Debit,Checking_Addition,Savings_Debit,Savings_Addition
2015-01-07,342.1,0.0,0.0,0.0
2015-01-07,981.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2015-01-07,3185.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2015-01-05,55.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2015-01-05,75.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2015-01-03,287.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2015-01-02,64.8,0.0,0.0,0.0
2015-01-02,75.0,0.0,0.0,75.0
2015-01-02,1280.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2015-01-02,245.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2015-01-01,45.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
```

In my code I start with the variables `checking_start` and `savings_start` that contain the start values of the checking and savings account.  I would like to give the code a start date and an end date and have the code iterate through each day, see if there was an expense on that day and subtract the checking and savings debits and add the checking and savings additions.  If there were no expenses on that day it should keep the accounts at the same value as the previous day.  In addition, I am trying to constrain myself to Pandas data frames in the implementation.  So far my code looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
from date time import date
check_start = 8500.0
savings_start = 4000.0
start_date = date(2017, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2017, 1, 8)
df = pd.read_csv(file_name.csv, dtype={'Date': str, 'Checking_Debit': float, 
                                       'Checking_Addition': float, 
                                       'Savings_Debit': float, 
                                       'Savings_Addition': float})
```

In a Pythonic format with the Pandas module, how do I walk through from the start date to the end date, one day at a time, then see if there is an expense or expenses on those date and then subtract that from the checking and savings.  At the end I should have an array for the value of the checking account on each date and the same for the savings account on that day.

The result should be arrays written into another .csv file with the following format.

```
Date,Checking,Savings
2017-01-07,1865.1,3925.0
2017-01-06,6373.2,3925.0
2017-01-05,6373.2,3925.0
2017-01-04,6503.2,3925.0
2017-01-03,6503.2,3925.0
2017-01-02,6790.2,3925.0
2017-01-01,8455.0,4000.0
```

Comment: can you post an example what your output should look like?

Comment: Absolutely, I just added the desired output

Comment: What have you tried so far?  The only code you've posted doesn't actually demonstrate an attempt at this objective, it just loads a CSV and sets variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading the data that you provided and identifying the date column in data with it

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"dat.csv", parse_dates=[0],dtype={'Checking_Debit': float, 
                                                               'Checking_Addition': float, 
                                                               'Savings_Debit': float, 
                                                               'Savings_Addition': float})
```

Set Date as index for better data manipulation.

```
df = df.set_index("Date")
```

Initialize all the variables for the loop

```
check_start = 8500.0
savings_start = 4000.0
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2015/1/1')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2015/1/8')
delta = pd.Timedelta('1 days') # time that needs to be added to start date
```

Now group the expense data w.r.t to each date

```
grp_df = df.groupby('Date').sum()
```

Now we will do `while` loop for create expense report for each day

```
expense_report = []
while start_date<=end_date:
    if start_date in df.index:
        savings_start += (grp_df.loc[start_date,"Savings_Addition"]-grp_df.loc[start_date,"Savings_Debit"])
        check_start += (grp_df.loc[start_date,"Checking_Addition"]-grp_df.loc[start_date,"Checking_Debit"])
        expense_report.append([start_date,check_start,savings_start])
    elif start_date not in df.index:
        expense_report.append([start_date,check_start,savings_start])

    start_date += delta
```

convert expense_report list to pandas `Dataframe`

```
df_exp_rpt = pd.DataFrame(expense_report,columns=["Date","Checking","Savings"])



 print(df_exp_rpt)
        Date    Checking    Savings
0   2015-01-01  8455.0  4000.0
1   2015-01-02  6790.2  4075.0
2   2015-01-03  6503.2  4075.0
3   2015-01-04  6503.2  4075.0
4   2015-01-05  6373.2  4075.0
5   2015-01-06  6373.2  4075.0
6   2015-01-07  1865.1  4075.0
7   2015-01-08  1865.1  4075.0
```

You can save to csv by

```
df_exp_rpt.to_csv("filename.csv")
```

Note: The saving column values are 4075 instead of 3925.0 because you have 75 value in saving_addition column in your original data

Comment: Thanks Sahil, this is a good start, but it is running into the same problem I have thus far.  The solutions kips January 4 and January 6, since there were no expenses on those days.  However, as I look at your solution, it appears that I can place an else statement after the `if start_date in df.index` line that should be able to handle that problem.